# PPAs not showing up in synaptic?

Tags: ppa, repository, synaptic

for some reason several PPAs are not visible in the side-panel of synaptic, nor are their apps available when searched for. but they are visible when clicking settings > repositories, and they all match current install which is precise 12.04, and all have check boxes checked.

the PPAs were added via terminal, which didn't report any issue when they were added, and also several other PPAs were added moments previous which are all present and correct.

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The apps of the PPAs are not visible until you click the reload button.

Then click "Origin" and select the PPA you want.

[image: Synaptic Manager]

Comment: I didn't think that it would have been necessary for me to state it in the original question, but yes, reloading was the first thing I did (by way of apt-get update) thanks all the same